# How to plot 2D gradient(rainbow) by using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to plot stress of beam by using matplotlib library.

I have calculated by using formulas and plot it for an example:

[image: Figure 1: Example of before and after of finite element of beam]

As Figure 1, you will see that the green beam has more stress at element 3 and also element 8 Thus if i fill the color by rainbow gradient,The over all of blue beam will be same color but The green beam will have different color by the element 3 and 8 will be going to red side more than others.

[image: example of stress plot]

Here is some of my code.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib as mpl

```
node_coordinate = {1: [0.0, 1.0], 2: [0.0, 0.0], 3: [4.018905, 0.87781], 4: [3.978008, -0.1229], 5: [1.983549, -0.038322], 6: [2.013683, 0.958586], 7: [3.018193, 0.922264],
                   8: [2.979695, -0.079299], 9: [1.0070439, 0.989987], 10: [0.9909098, -0.014787999999999999]}
element_stress = {'1': 0.2572e+01, '2': 0.8214e+00, '3': 0.5689e+01, '4': -0.8214e+00, '5': -0.2572e+01, '6': -0.4292e+01, '7': 0.4292e+01, '8': -0.5689e+01}

cmap = mpl.cm.jet

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 2))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.80, 0.9, 0.15])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.4, 0.9, 0.15])
# ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.2572e+01, 0.8214e+00, 0.5689e+01, -0.8214e+00, -0.2572e+01, -0.4292e+01, 0.4292e+01, -0.5689e+01])
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1)
cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax1, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, orientation='vertical')
cb2 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax2, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

You will see that i know all of node co-ordinate and also element's stress value.

p.s. Sorry for my grammar, I'm not native.

Thank you. For suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried [`pcolormesh`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh.html) ([example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/quadmesh_demo.html))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/tricontour_demo.html), I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri
import numpy as np

node_coordinate = {1: [0.0, 1.0], 2: [0.0, 0.0], 3: [4.018905, 0.87781],
                   4: [3.978008, -0.1229], 5: [1.983549, -0.038322],
                   6: [2.013683, 0.958586], 7: [3.018193, 0.922264],
                   8: [2.979695, -0.079299], 9: [1.0070439, 0.989987],
                   10: [0.9909098, -0.014787999999999999]}
element_stress = {1: 0.2572e+01, 2: 0.8214e+00, 3: 0.5689e+01,
                  4: -0.8214e+00, 5: -0.2572e+01, 6: -0.4292e+01,
                  7: 0.4292e+01, 8: -0.5689e+01}

n = len(element_stress.keys())
x = np.empty(n)
y = np.empty(n)
d = np.empty(n)

for i in element_stress.keys():
    x[i-1] = node_coordinate[i][0]
    y[i-1] = node_coordinate[i][1]
    d[i-1] = element_stress[i]

triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)

cmap = mpl.cm.jet
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))

ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.80, 0.9, 0.15])
ax1.tricontourf(triang, d, cmap=cmap)

ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.4, 0.9, 0.15])
x_2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
       0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y_2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
d_2 = x_2[:]
triang_2 = tri.Triangulation(x_2, y_2)
ax2.tricontourf(triang_2, d_2, cmap=cmap)

fig.show()
```

[image]

The second example was added for clarification, as the graph obtained from the given data is not the same as you got from Comsol.